# Discord message monitoring without using a self-bot?

Tags: discord

Is there a way to monitor messages in Discord without using a self-bot since it's against ToS? I want to monitor certain channels in each of my servers and mirror into my private server to make it easier to read and react to the information coming in that I care the most about instead of scrolling through each server for that specific channel(s).

I thought of using a kind of script for the web app and console to send to a webhook in my server but I'm not sure how to setup a on_message kind of event for console.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible in python by the use of websockets. You can try something like this:

```
import websocket
import json

url = "wss://gateway.discord.gg/?encoding=json&v=9"

payload = {
            "op":2,
            "d":{
                "token":"your token",
                "properties":{
                    "$os":"",
                    "$browser":"",
                    "$device":""}
    }
}

ws = websocket.WebSocket()

ws.connect(url)

while True:
    print(ws.recv())
```

You can find a more detailed code [here](https://gist.github.com/centipede000/40dca4f7e5fb19470b0401cf49bbaa33)